# Android Nougat devices not supporting java.util.Base64 library

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I've been given few jar files which use java.util.Base64 to encode and decode data, when i try to get response from a network call using these jars to parse the data, i'm getting `Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/Base64;`  but it works properly in API >= 26 any idea how to fix this issue? because i can't change those Jars

Comment: you really have to check the class/method documentation before asking such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [`java.util.Base64` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64), it was only added in API 26. The only API prior to that point is the [`android.util.Base64` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64), which has a significantly different API.

Comment: Looks like i can't do much rather restricting minimum API level to 26 then.